# Distributing a list of numbers between sets to minimize number of sets

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a circular list of numbers (last element is considered adjacent to first):

```
10 10 10 10 9 8 10 8 19
```

and I want to distribute them among sets of at most a given size such that each set contains consecutive numbers.

For this example, say my set size is 48.

I can do straightforward `{10 10 10 10}, {9 8 10 8}, {19}`  thus yielding 3 sets.

But I can also do `{10 10 10 9 8}, {10 8 19 10}` - 2 sets (remember list is circular).

How can I calculate minimum number of sets that can contain all numbers? Preferably O(n) with respect to both computation and memory.

Comment: To clarify, you need to partition this circular list (not really a set!) of numbers into the minimum number of sublists such that the sum of the numbers in each sublist is less than or equal to the "set size" (in your example, 48). Is that correct?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that an O(n) solution exists?

Comment: I can think of one ;)
You can move your range (start,end) so that what's in between is still not greater than set size and keep track of what position in the list you have reached in how many steps. Once you loop (at most with all starting positions) you will have a solution.
the issue with this is that there is not necessairly a single starting point for any ending point your range (as the span may change in lenght) so you need to keep track of a number of results which increases memory footprint and is slower. I cannot yet find any way to keep only one such point

Comment: Then why are you asking?

Comment: sorry, auto-post turned on before comment was ready ;) My solution is O(n) but still flawed

Comment: O(1) solution: use a single set, and put all the elements in it.

Comment: won't do - set is size-bound

Comment: OK, I missed that, but also your question is unclear: if you are told the *maximum* size for each set then write that, don't write "sets of a fixed size", write "sets of at most a given size".  I see the first commenter asked for clarification on this too; please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: that should be clear from the example. Anyway I changed the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is linear time.

So you have an array, like `[10 10 10 10 9 8 10 8 19]` and a bound like `48`.

The first step is to figure out all of the maximal groups of consecutive elements whose sum is below your bound.  Doing this we're going to populate another array with the position that the next consecutive group has to start at if you have one starting here.

To do this we keep track of where we start from, and where we go to, and the total of our current range.  Whenever our total is under our bound, we advance the end and add to the total.  Whenever our total is above the bound we mark the start of the next range for the `start` as `end`, advance `start`, and subtract that element from the `total`.  We continue until either we find that everything goes into one range (in which case your final answer is 1) or `start` wraps around.

In this stage we are always advancing a pointer, we can advance `end` at most `2n` times (more than that we have a wrap and stop) and end `n` times (until it wraps) so this is `O(n)` so far.

Now we can build from the end backwards the answer to the connected questions, "How many groups until I wrap around?" and "Where do I wrap around to with this many groups?" For those positions at the end that wrap, the answers are 1 and whatever your `next_start` is.  For earlier ones, the answers are "one more group than my `next_start`" and "to the place that `next_start` jumps to`.  This is another`n`operations for`O(n)` still.

Now we can scan the array for candidate start positions.  A candidate start position is one that wraps to itself or farther.  The size of the partition you get is "the number of groups until I wrap around".  Your answer is the candidate start position with the minimum number of groups.  This is again a `O(n)` step and gives you the answer.

Therefore your maximum running time is `O(n)`.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar! 
This is precisely what I had in mind. It only pains me that I was so close to this solution yet missed one step and followed wrong direction that proved to be a dead end. Anyway, this solution is perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You want to partition your data into sequences such that the total of each sequence does not exceed some constant.

Choose a starting point for the first sequence, say, 0. Greedily add elements to this sequence, then to the next sequence, and so on, until you have consumed all the data. This is one possible partition.

To make another partition, start from position 1. Again consume all the data greedily. This is another possible partition. Then do the same starting from position 2, and so on. You can stop once you have used every starting point that falls within the first sequence of the first partition that you made. Any further starting points will only result in a partition that is identical to one of the earlier ones you made.

```
data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 8, 19]
max_size = 48
n = len(data)

# make a partition starting from position 0
bounds = [0]
total = 0
for pos in range(n):
  x = data[pos]
  if total + x <= max_size:
    total += x
  else:
    bounds.append(pos)
    total = x

# the first partition ends here
limit = bounds[1]
best_bounds = bounds

# make all other possible partitions
for start in range(1, limit):
  bounds = [start]
  total = 0
  pos = start
  while True:
    x = data[pos]
    if total + x <= max_size:
      total += x
    else:
      bounds.append(pos)
      total = x
    pos = (pos + 1) % n
    if pos == start:
      break
  if len(bounds) < len(best_bounds):
    best_bounds = bounds

# assemble and display the best partition
partition = []
sequence = []
start = best_bounds[0]
index = 1
pos = start
while True:
  if pos == best_bounds[index]:
    partition.append(sequence)
    if pos == start:
      break
    sequence = []
    index = (index+1)%len(best_bounds)
  sequence.append(data[pos])
  pos = (pos + 1) % n
print('partition of size %d: %s' % (len(partition), partition))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, this solution however is somewhat flawed for large ranges, if my set size spans 3/4 of the list effectively all subsets will be of size 2, but i'll have to go through the whole list O(n) times which is painful.

Comment: Another approach is to incrementally advance the first partition until you have explored all possible partitions. This will run faster in the case you describe. However, it will take quadratic time in cases where you have small sequences. I'm not sure there is a linear-time solution. My intuition tells me that there isn't.

Comment: Another way to improve performance is to precompute the bounds of every possible sequence. This can be done with a single traversal of the data. Using the resulting index will make it faster to test partitions, but it still won't do asympotically better than quadratic time.

Comment: One more observation: you can speed up the search by starting from the smallest sequence of the first partition rather than the first sequence. Of course, this still doesn't get you linear time.